# CM7 messaging shows only date, not time

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, cyanogenmod, sms, date-and-time

I have installed cyanogenmod 7.2.0.1-bravo on my HTC Desire.

For messages received before today the messaging app shows only the date without the time.  (For today it shows only the time.)

Furthermore there is no "message details" option in the menu to view the complete date+time for any message.

How can I view the time of older messages?

Comment: try to download a better messaging app from the market like [Handsent](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.handcent.nextsms)

Comment: If it's really important, you could just go through the databases in /data/data/blah.messaging.blah/databases/ and it should have them there. (Also, I'm not sure that's where it is, but they should be stored somewhere in /data.)